# exiting recursive loop - python

Tags: python, loops, recursion, exit

I am writing a small collision check function. If 'is_collision" function return 'True' the function 'extend_until' should stop executing all the recursive functions and return the start point of the corresponding loop. I am not quite sure how this should be executed.

I have a discretization resolution of 1.0 unit along the length and hence starting initial if condition in 'extend until' function.

```
def is_collision(query):
    print "Collision occurred"
    return True


def extend_until(start, goal):
    if goal-start <= 1.0:
        if is_collision(goal):
            # if YES all recursion should stop and return.
            return start
    else:
        midpoint = (start+goal)/2
        extend_until(start, midpoint)
        extend_until(midpoint, goal)

    return goal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 4
    new_configuration = extend_until(p1, p2)
    print new_configuration
```

Comment: You are not using recursion here. You need to return the function to make it recursive. Inside else loop, instead of `extend_until(start,midpoint)` it could be `return  extend_until(start,midpoint)`. But there are 2 statements that you are using there. Also, `return goal` should not be present. It will not work with this setup. Please tell more about what should be input and output to function extend_until and what it should exactly do..

Comment: Input to 'extend function' is usually 2 points. In this case the points are 1 dimensional. 
GOAL: discretize the distance between two given input points (in above case resolution is 1.0) and check for each discrete point if its a collision free. If collision function  returns True that whole recursion should stop and return the value.

Comment: And what is the function supposed to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough?

```
def is_collision(start, goal):
    if goal-start <= 1.0:
        print('Collision occurred')
        return True
    return False


def extend_until(start, goal):
    print("Start is: "+str(start))
    if is_collision(start, goal):
        # if YES all recursion should stop and return.
        return goal-start
    else:
        #midpoint = (start+goal)/2
        #extend_until(start, midpoint)
        start = start + 1
        return extend_until(start, goal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 4
    new_configuration = extend_until(p1, p2)
    print('New Configuration is: '+ str(new_configuration))
```

Output:-

```
Start is: 0
Start is: 1
Start is: 2
Start is: 3
Collision occurred
New Configuration is: 1
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijeetk431 for you effort. But this isn't the output i am looking for.
p1 = 0 , p2 = 4 an my resolution is 1.0. Which means that i have to check collision for [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] in sequential order. For above mentioned sample code, the ' is_collision ' function return True by default, Which mean that upon checking is_collision(1.0) gives me True and every thing should terminate returning 1.0 and assigning it to new_configuration.

Comment: Edited the previous answer. Please let know if this works for you